# How to make a pivot table in SAS

Tags: sas, pivot-table

I have the following table

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| ID     | var_name | var_value |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 153879 | age      | 35        |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 153879 | gender   | Male      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 153879 | income   | 1000      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 13527  | age      | 18        |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 13527  | gender   | Male      |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 13527  | income   | 20        |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 14416  | age      | 40        |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 14416  | gender   | Female    |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| 14416  | income   | 500       |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

How can I make a pivot table out of this so the result looks like this

```
+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| ID     | age | gender | income |
+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| 153879 | 35  | Male   | 1000   |
+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| 13527  | 18  | Male   | 20     |
+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| 14416  | 40  | Female | 500    |
+--------+-----+--------+--------+
```

I tried doing it by repeatedly left joining the table on itself in this way:

```
data table;
    input id $ var_name $ var_value $;
datalines;
153879 age 35
153879 gender Male
153879 income 1000
13527  age 18
13527  gender Male
13527  income 20
14416  age 40
14416  gender Female
14416  income 500
run;


Proc SQL;
    Create table have as
    Select a.ID
          ,b.var_value as age
          ,c.var_value as gender
          ,d.var_value as income
    From (select distinct id from table) as a
    Left Join (select * from table where var_name = 'age') as b
        On a.id = b.id
    Left Join (select * from table where var_name = 'gender') as c
        On a.id = c.id
    Left Join (select * from table where var_name = 'income') as d
        On a.id = d.id;
Quit;
```

Using this code I get the required results, however, since the real table is several times larger and includes over 50 variables, I would like to know if there is any other way to do this, which is more efficient and short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose your table with `PROC TRANSPOSE`.  You will first need to sort it or index it by `id` and pre-aggregate the values if there are any duplicate values of `id` and `var_name`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table have_aggregated as 
        select id
             , var_name
             , sum(var_value) as var_value
        from have
        group by id, var_name
        order by id, var_name
    ;
quit;

proc transpose data=have_aggregated
               out=want(drop=_NAME_);
    by id;
    id var_name;
    var var_value;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solved everything but I have one question. What if I have some IDs which have duplicate var_name values. For example if ID 153879 has two income values? In that case the above code gives the following error ```ERROR: The ID value "Income" occurs twice in the same BY group.``` Assuming I want to sum both values into one, how would the code look like?

Comment: You will need to pre-aggregate them first by `id` and `var_name`. I have updated the code with this change. It will aggregate and sort in one step.